# python HTTP request is not working properly

Tags: python

So I am trying to code that registers an account on a squarespace website. I fired up Fiddler and intercept the HTTP requests, saw the `POST` request that sends the form data:

[image]

so I wrote this code in Python:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

data = {
    'firstName': 'joe',
    'lastName': 'channel',
    'accountLoginOrigin': 'signup',
    'password': 'pass12345',
    'confirmPassword': 'pass12345',
    'email': 'flff30@mxi_w.com'
}

r = session.post('http://miniview.squarespace.com/api/site-users/account/profile', data=data,verify=False)
r.text

u'{"message":"User must be logged in to access this resource."}
```

What's my mistake with this Python request?

It's strange because I'm expected to be logged before I can register.

Edit:

The first person that answered me said i should look into the cookies which i did, now i am trying to manually add cookies to the request session cookieJar but something is unclear to me. This request

```
POST https://minnicow.squarespace.com/api/census/RecordHit HTTP/1.1
Host: minicow.squarespace.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-CSRF-Token: BToh7ecmmp4cYzg0YjI3OTQ3MjI5Nzk1MGE2ZWZkZTQ1OTQwOTIw
Content-Length: 741
Origin: https://minicow.squarespace.com
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://minicow.squarespace.com/
Cookie: crumb=BToh7ecmmp4cYzg0YjI3OTQ3MjI5Nzk1MGE2ZWZkZTQ1OTQwOTIw; ss_cvr=014571ee-fb3f-498c-b2a0-a9b5c470f9af|1576941479208|1576941479208|1576941479208|1; ss_cvt=1576941479208

event=1&data=%7B%22localStorageSupported%22%3Atrue%2C%22queryString%22%3A%22%22%2C%22referrer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22websiteId%22%3A%225dfd4479a068b47518c09b20%22%2C%22templateId%22%3A%225c5a519771c10ba3470d8101%22%2C%22website_locale%22%3A%22en-US%22%2C%22userAgent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%3B%20rv%3A71.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F71.0%22%2C%22clientDate%22%3A1576941479207%2C%22viewportInnerHeight%22%3A790%2C%22viewportInnerWidth%22%3A1536%2C%22screenHeight%22%3A864%2C%22screenWidth%22%3A1536%2C%22url%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Home%22%2C%22collectionId%22%3A%225dfd45313ef7d373d3d9a389%22%7D&ss_cvr=014571ee-fb3f-498c-b2a0-a9b5c470f9af%7C1576941479208%7C1576941479208%7C1576941479208%7C1
```

responds with this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Sat, 21 Dec 2019 15:18:08 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=0
set-cookie: ss_cid=40ec759f-0ef6-4c31-a7c8-d8c1f2127d8a; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20-Dec-2021 15:18:09 GMT; Max-Age=63072000
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
set-cookie: ss_cvisit=1576941489288; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 21-Dec-2019 15:48:09 GMT; Max-Age=1800
set-cookie: ss_cpvisit=1576941489288; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 20-Dec-2021 15:18:09 GMT; Max-Age=63072000
content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-contextid: kpeBSI9l/GOyKGPyu
server: Squarespace

11
{"success": true}
0
```

I.e three new cookies are set (ss_cid, ss_cvisit and ss_cpvisit) .. when i tried to recreate this request in python requests, i get the same success message in the response body but these 3 new cookies are not being set.

Then i noticed that the request header contains three cookies - i was able to set the first one  (crub cookie), but  could not figure out how the other two cookies (ss_cvr and ss_cvt ) are being set.

I checked the whole fiddler log right from where the page is loaded to the point where this request is made, i could not find where they are set. I also search their values in the preceding responses i couldn't find them, while ss_cvt looks like Epoch form of the time was made while ss_cvr hasthe  form "UUID()|ss_cvt|ss_cvt|ss_cvt|1" . i tried generating and substituting those values in the request but nothing works.

I am trying to get this to work, but it is obvious that i need help

Comment: may you need to bring some cookie ?

Comment: If you inspect the singup source code you'll see that you also need to provide a `requestId` and probably some other headers also...The `requestId` changes every time you reload the page so you'll probably need to use some web-scraping...

Comment: @RubiJihantoro i thought python sessions stores cookie? because i first navigate to the registration page using sessions.get()

Comment: @game0ver i inspected the page. i could not find it, how do i go about this pls

Comment: You might want to edit the text in your Fiddler output, since you took the time to edit out that information in the image you probably dont want it posted as plaintext?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using session?

`r = requests.post(url = <URL>, data = data)`

This should work?

Comment: because of all the cookies that are involved. i can't figure out a way to manually add the cookies to the request. using session() is to enable the request and response cookies stored automatically

Comment: Mhm. Never dealt with cookies. Extremely interesting. Do you know what your cookie is? `cookies = {'cooking': 'known_cookie_as_string'}` and then `r = requests.post(url= <URL>, data=data , cookies=cookies)`